# Order microposts by votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I can't figure out how to format the code here.  I relisted the question here (in nicer fashion): http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=43839

Have a simple microposts site with voting functionality.  I want to be able to display the posted microposts by votes.size.  I can not seem to get it to work and would appreciate some guidance.

MODELS:

```
class Micropost
  attr_accessible :content
  has_many :votes 
  belongs_to :user 
  default_scope :order => 'microposts.created_at DESC'


class Vote
  belongs_to :micropost
```

VIEWS:

```
# microposts page
<% unless @picture.microposts.empty? %>
  <table class="microposts" summary="User microposts">
    <%= render @microposts %>
  </table>
<% end %>

# microposts partial
<tr>
  <td class="micropost">   
    <span class="gravatar">     
      <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, :size => '60'), micropost.user %>
    </span>
    <span class="content" >
      <%= micropost.content %>
    </span>
    <span id="vote_total_<%= micropost.id %>" class="micropost_votes">
      votes:<%= micropost.votes.size %>
    </span>
  <% if current_page?(root_path) && signed_in? %>
    <span id="vote_button">
      <%= button_to 'vote', micropost_votes_path(:micropost_id => micropost),
          :remote => true 
      %>
    </span>
  <% end %>  
  </td>
</tr>
```

CONTROLLERS:

```
# VotesController
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  @vote      = @micropost.votes.build params[:micropost_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @vote.save
      format.html { redirect_to @micropost }
      format.js        
    else
      format.html { redirect_to root }
    end
  end
end
```

I've been able to sort the microposts by the created_at date, but I can not seem to sort the microposts by the micropost.votes.size.  It seems to have something to do with ordering one model based on the state of a different model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was the best solution that I found. On the view where the microposts are rendered, I added:

```
.sort_by { |micropost| micropost.votes.size }
```

So the actual render code looks like this:

```
<%= render @microposts.sort_by { |micropost| micropost.votes.size } %>
```

I actually reversed my posts so that the posts with the highest vote totals were on top.  This is easy:

```
<%= render @microposts.sort_by { |micropost| micropost.votes.size }.reverse %>
```

I have NO idea if this will create problems with database performance, but it seems to be working well.

Comment: I think it is better to delegate such operations to models, rather than views.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Micropost.all(:select => "#{Micropost.table_name}.*, COUNT(#{Vote.table_name}.id) number_of_votes",
         :joins => :votes,
         :order => "number_of_votes desc")
```

Comment: Cool.  A couple questions:  (1) This looks like a controller command, but seems like it should go in routes. Controller?  (2) Would the number_of_votes method go in the Votes model?

Comment: the code snippet i post above will retrive all Microposts ordered by how many votes they have. It doesn't have anything to do with routing. You can put this inside your model (to better encapsulate it) or put it in you controller. number_of_votes is not a method. Its part of the SQL query. The code snippet should work as is without you needing to add any extra methods.

Comment: Well I think this is close.  Except it only shows me the micropost with the most votes.  It doesn't actually show them all ordered.  It only shows 1 micropost.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: Yes. And, I still want to show microposts that have zero votes.

Comment: thekindofme, I can not get this query to work.  I have played with it for a couple of days in the console, but it either gives me ONE micropost back (which has the highest vote total), or it just gives me the vote total back in their original, unordered pattern.  You have any other ideas or places I can go to understand this more?